# How can I activate custom fields checkbox in pages?

Tags: custom-field

Please help me guys newbie here. I can't find the custom fields checkbox in the pages menu, even after I have clicked screen options in WP 4.8.1. Thanks in advance! [image: where is the custom fields checkbox]

Answer (score 1):

You will find the option when editing the page, just click in the `Home` link:

[image]

select it there and it will be for all the pages from now on:

[image]